# Inflated Size Webhost Fixed Ad? (on bottom)

Tags: html, web

What would cause this webhost ad to be so big? (on bottom)
https://scottschmidtportfolio.000webhostapp.com/

This is the size it is suppose to be?
https://solenoidal-slate.000webhostapp.com/

Would you think it is something in my code? I deleted all the code and then remade it.

Sorry if this is in the wrong section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the img style in `style.css` at line number: `91`
Like this:

```
img {
   overflow: hidden;
   /*width: 240px; 
   height: 109px; 
   min-width: 240px; 
   min-height: 200px; 
   max-width: 240px; 
   max-height: 110px; */
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

`img` is a general selector so it affect all the image tag. Try to use more specific selector targeted to one particular element. I can see all the images in your site are stretched I think it's because of above code.

Comment: I deleted the widths/heights and then removed the entire IMG tag.  It didn't seem to work (but sometimes might have a refresh time). Dont think it worked. It could be a webhost error...thanks for try

Comment: Please clear the browser cache, and try one more time. It's working for me.

Comment: You need to style the portfolio image separately. I think it is broken after the edit

Comment: I have been messing around the the scripts from other issue might of been from that too.

Comment: Oh, What i can do :(

Comment: ok. Well this one is fixed! Marked as answer. I went onto the website on IE and yeah you are right was the cache... the bootstrap is back up i found the important one I believe..

Comment: Ill fix the porfolio images shouildnt be too bad. In the meantime, if you have time LOL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835015/auto-typing-function-refreshes-and-then-scrolls-up-on-mobile-phones

Comment: Yeah, You need to fix that immediately because it's a web design studio website