# Drop Down Menu Click

Tags: javascript, html, nav

Should be an easy question...
My NAV Bar Template (working): https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/GMzgKz

...imported into my Portfolio (is NOT working): https://scottschmidtportfolio.000webhostapp.com/#
 The menu is not going down on click(the menu appears when the screen is smaller).

What is causing this? I have a feeling it is something within my scripts (below):
 EDIT NEW UPDATED SCRIPTS from https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>SS Studio</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fab417e5fd.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the console:

[image]

Make sure Bootstrap loaded correctly. It look like you are trying to add bootstrap in three places.

Better to use CDNetworks. Here is the link for bootstrap [cdn](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

Also you had one script error:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('nav').addClass('shrink');
       } else {
         $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
       }
   });
 // }); // remove this
```

#### Caution:

You're using HTTPS but some resources are requested in an insecure way. use `https://` for including all the resources like images, css, js, etc

Comment: Ok. I will give it a try. My training from freecodecamp never taught scripts/live servers so now that I am in the real world a lot of these script stuff is causing me trouble.

Comment: Please fix all the comment suggested :)

Comment: Ok. I edited in my new scripts into original post. And deleted the second }); Currently working on the https thing...

Comment: You by chance know whats causing the webhost ad to be super big? If you're bored....    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985798/inflated-size-webhost-fixed-ad-on-bottom

Comment: Uh Oh, deleted a script I wasnt supposed to all the boostrap/nav bar disapeared. Haha. I saved an old copy I will add one in at a time to see which one was the "important" one?

Comment: Checking by removing one at time, You would find important one in the process :)

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">   This one seems to be powering a lot of the site's bootstrap....

Comment: I converted the CSS LESS to just CSS. Should make a HUGE difference but still not 100% working. I think I am getting close to solving this....